# Yii Set default value if no value selected On insert

Tags: php, yii

This is my model

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['created_by, updated_by, update_note,institution_code', 'safe' ],
            ['institution_code', 'default', 
             'value' => Yii::app()->user->getState('institution_code'),
             'setOnEmpty' => FALSE, 
             'on' => 'insert' 
           ],
       ];
    }
```

If institution code is selected ,save that value

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Model shoudn't work with sessions and also request data. You should set `Yii::app()->user->getState('institution_code')` manualy.

Comment: I want to save the institution code if selected ,otherwise save the session value

Comment: What version do you use? Yii or Yii2? As you calling `Yii::app()` for 1 version and in tags you have also 2.

Comment: you must set `institution_code` in session, before using it.

Comment: YII,I already set institution_code in session,

Comment: every time the sesion value is saved,I couldn't save the selected value

Comment: you are setting any default value in session for `institution_code`?

Comment: Iam using default scope

Comment: public function defaultScope() {
   $t = $this->getTableAlias(false, false);
            $institution_code = Yii::app()->user->getState('institution_code');
            $check_institution = '';
            if( $institution_code != '' )
                $check_institution = " AND $t.institution_code = {$institution_code} ";

Comment: defaultScope using only when you select data related to model.

Comment: You were not setting session using `setState()` or may be i am missing something.

Comment: I already set session value

Comment: then you will easily get that value using  session variable name.

Comment: yes, but if the session value is null ,I want  to save the selected value

Comment: Default value work when you pass NULL value in attribute else it will get whatever value you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change setOnEmpty TRUE

```
[ 'institution_code', 'default', 'value'      => Yii::app()->user->getState('institution_code'),
                    'setOnEmpty' => TRUE, 'on' => 'insert' ],
```